# How to make a algebraic data type list

Tags: haskell

Hi I'm currently trying to use the elem function in prelude.

```
data MyType = A Int
            | B Int Int
            | C Int
            | D Int Int
     deriving (Show,Eq)

list = [ A _, B _ _ ]
```

or

```
list = [ A Int, B Int Int ]

bool = (A 12) elem list  -- use like this to get a Boolean value.
```

The problem is the list, it will (both) have compile error.  Can someone tell me the right way to define list?

Oops about the data and deriving (Show,Eq) in my main code I did do all that.  The reason for this question is that I have a big list of MyType and I want to cherry pick one or two of the types out of the big list modify it then put it back, how do I do that?
Exp.
bigList=[ A 3, C 6, A 5, B 5 8, D 5 6 ]
I would like to pick out only the data type ( A Int ) and (B Int Int) , maybe change all value for the two data type into 0, after modification put back so I end up with a new list.
newBigList=[ A 0, C 6, A 0, B 0 0, D 5 6 ]

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? the above isn't valid Haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, it is `data` and not `Data`.
Second, you are mixing type variables (`Int`) with values in defining `list`, while `_` can only be used in pattern matching. You should write this instead to build a list of type `[MyType]`:

```
list = [A 12, B 1 5]
```

Third, your declaration for `bool` uses `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` as an infix operator, while it is a function like any other. Write either

```
bool = elem (A 12) list
```

or

```
bool = (A 12) `elem` list
```

As you see from the type signature of `elem`, you need to derive the `Eq` typeclass. It could be useful to be able to print your `MyType` values also, so you may consider adding `deriving (Eq,Show)` at the end of your type declaration.

It seems like you're mistaking Haskell for Prolog. Haskell do not work by unification like Prolog. You should start reading a good tutorial or book from the basics.

Comment: I think you should also mention the fact that the type of `elem` is `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` :-)

Comment: Ooops, I did not try compiling the code and I completely missed that :)